# Play video after 10 sec with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to play the video after 10 sec. The function of setTimeOut does not seem to work. 
This is the javascript function:

```
$('.top').toggle( 3000 );
$('.top1').delay(3000).toggle(3000);
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".video").play();
}, 6000);
```

The html part:

```
<video class="video" width="700" height="700">
    <source src="images/video9.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="imagesvideo9.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video></div>
<img class="top" src="images/boot.png" style="display:none; hidden; position:absolute; left:-1%; top:8.5%;" width="710" />
<img class="top1" src="images/boot1.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:-1%; top:75%;" width="710"/>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `play()` method is on the HTMLVideoElement, not a jQuery object. Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".video")[0].play(); // note the [0] to access the native element
}, 10000); // 10 seconds = 10000 ms
```